# Delete multiple rows of data in JSP based on check box selection(AJAX)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am working on a requirement which is as below.

I am storing a list of objects(each object is having a unique id) as session parameter and displaying each object data in a table in jsp using JSTL as below

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${PlayerList}">

<tr>
        <td>
<img  style="cursor:pointer" src="./images/delete.jpg" title="Force Delete" 
onClick="forceDelete(${list.playerId})">
        <td>${list.playerName}</td>
        <td>${list.runsScored}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And the AJAX function is

```
   <script>
function forceDelete(playerIdValue)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            var toDelete= confirm("Do you want to Remove?")
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {

document.getElementById('display_div').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            if (toDelete== true)
            {
                xmlhttp.open("POST","PlayerController?
 value="+playerIdValue,true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }
        }
   </script>
```

I am handling the deleting row in PlayerController servlet's POST method

Now i want to implement something like below

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${PlayerList}">

<tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox">
        <td>${list.playerName}</td>
        <td>${list.runsScored}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
<input type="button" value="delete">
```

The user can select multiple check boxes and hit the delete button then the respective rows should be deleted from JSP using AJAX

How should i proceed on this,any help would be appreciated.

If any additional data is needed, i am ready to provide.

Thanks in advance.

I tried this but didn't seem to work,tell me where i am doing wrong.

Checkbox code `

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toBeDeleted[]" value="${list.playerId}">
<div align="center"><button onclick="forceStop()">Delete</button></div>
```

JS code

```
function forceStop()
        {
            var toBeDeleted = new Array();
            $("input:checked").each(function() {
            data['toBeDeleted[]'].push($(this).val());
            });

            $.ajax({
             url:"PlayerController",
             type:"POST",
             dataType:'json',
             data: {toBeDeleted:toBeDeleted},
             success:function(data){
            },
            });
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did and it's working perfectly fine

In JSP, inside JS function

```
function forceStop()
        {

            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('toBeDeleted');
            var selected = new Array();
            for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
                }
            }

                $.ajax({
                    url:"PlayerController",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:'json',
                    data: {toDelete:selected},
                    success:function(data){
                      alert("SUCCESS");
                    },
                });

        }
```

Inside servlet i retrieved the array as below.

```
String[] toDelete = request.getParameterValues("toDelete[]");
    int[] toBeDeleted=new int[toDelete.length];
    for(int i=0;i<toDelete.length;i++)
    {
        toBeDeleted[i]=Integer.parseInt(toDelete[i]);
    }
```

We need to parse every element to integer as they will be parsed as Strings by AJAX.

from controller i did batch deletion using DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Approach that needs to followed without the exact code details:

1. Provide name and value attribute to your check boxes with value being id of player
2. On click of delete get list of all checked boxes,which will get you an array of values i.e. array of player ids
3. This array needs to be passed via ajax request to your servlet,which retrieves the listing and deletes all records.

In case of any concerns,will post pseudo code as well.

Comment: Edited question based on what i tried,but it is not working,tell me where i am doing wrong

Comment: looks like i am able to collect the id of players,when i hit the delete button,i can see the ids of players in url bar,what i want to know how i can recieve them in the servlet and perform delete operation on DB

Comment: 1)Are you able to get player ids in array 2)If yes,check in browser console if it is correctly sent via ajax request 3)What is received at servlet end?

Comment: how did you retrieve parameter before in servlet?Try using the same way with the checkbox name this time!

Comment: I tried with some debugging,the process is never coming to POST method,there is something wrong with Jquery code it seems.

Comment: yes,it was working fine with single field,but the thing is i didn't use Jquery in previous case,now i am using Jquery to collect the array of Ids,may be that is causing the problem. You post the code according to your thoughts,i will try that once.

Comment: Kindly post the URL being sent via AJAX url being posted by your request!Add it to the post itself

Comment: Whatever the Jquery i tried,it's not working it seems,post some pseudo code that can help on this matter.